# Dynamic including/autoload of external TypoScript templates

Tags: dynamic, include, typo3, autoload, typoscript

Is it possible to include automatically all external TS templates in some folders to avoid manual linking ?

Instead of writing each time manually **INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT** like this :

**Constants :**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/1.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/2.ts">
...
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/999.ts">
```

**Setup :**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/constants/1.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/constants/2.ts">
...
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/constants/999.ts">
```

I would like to have something like this instead of manual include file per file :

**Constants :**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT_ALL: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/constants/">
```

**Setup :**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT_ALL: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/">
```

*Recursive* option could be helpful also.

Is it possible, or I need to hack the core to realize such functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is including sub-files in one main file. It's similar approach like using `@import` in `CSS` files for including other substyles.

Then you can just include one file in your TS:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/setup/main.ts">
```

and at the main.ts you can paste additional `includes`

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using exactly such method, it's manual. I would like to make it automatic.

Comment: I doubt if it's possible. To confirm: we are using such including in many projects and it works, but didn't find any way for autoload. From my experience I can say that's not a drama, normally there's about 30-40 files per implementation and it's required to create only once 'template structure', in next projects you just use it and add only new items.

Comment: It depends of size of the project and which level of precision of Your structure You want. Currently I have 160 files on one of my projects. It begins to be too much for manual including :)

Comment: wow, that's really a lot. In really big projects we use up to ~60 files max. Of course we don't place every `lib` in separate file, if you have 4 menus on one page they also can be placed in one ts, one file for all elements of the single TV DataStructure, etc. To big granulation becomes uncomfortable even with best VCS.

Comment: Yep. Its quite complex installation with more than 100 extensions, with multiple TS templates. BTW, question is not in chosen VCS, even if it's important, but in wise project hierarchy.